# How to write default hooks for a multi users repo on bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket, devops, githooks, pre-commit-hook

I have a git repo on bitbucket cloud and a dozen users working on him.
I wish to define/write hooks for pre-commit checks for every user cloning the repo to his local workspace without every user needed to define or drag the hooks himself.

As far as I understand no such option is available via bitbucket option (exists only for bitbucket server services which are self-hosted).

Comment: Hooks on Bitbucket Cloud are applied through their [Java plugin framework](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/using-repository-hooks-776639836.html). 
 You can check in the Atlassian Marketplace if a plugin already does what you want, or create your own.

Comment: Like I mentioned - 
"As far as I understand no such option is available via bitbucket option (exists only for bitbucket server services which are self-hosted)."

And I'm looking for a Bitbucket cloud option.